# Why does font-awesome icon not show after deploying?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, fonts, font-awesome

In my Spring MVC App I am using some Font Awesome icons. They work fine, when I test the application locally.
But when I deploy the war file to a linux server, the icons are not shown.

I checked the page, and in my opinion all resources are found.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

found out, that there was an error in the pom.xml. The resources were missing in the war file.